# Choosing values from multiple columns based on latest value of one column

Tags: t-sql, group-by, max, cosmos-db

I have an Azure Cosmos DB that contains columns DateTime, userName, temperature, and bloodPressure, plus many other columns. There are several distinct userName values, and each userName has temperature and bloodPressure data collected at different values of DateTime. The temperature and bloodPressure values are different for each of those 15 times.

Here is an example of the data,

```
userName, DateTime, bloodPressure, temperature, heartBeat, hatSize
Curly, "2021-01-19 18:24:53", 121, 98, 60, 7.25
Larry, "2021-01-14 18:24:53", 125, 99, 80, 7.5
Mo, "2021-01-13 18:24:53", 123, 100, 70, 7.75
Curly, "2021-01-18 18:24:53", 120, 97, 50, 8
Larry, "2021-01-13 18:24:53", 119, 99, 75, 7.15
Larry, "2021-01-15 18:24:53", 115, 98, 85, 7.37
Mo, "2021-01-12 18:24:53", 110, 102, 100, 8.01
Mo, "2021-01-20 18:24:53", 130, 99, 110, 6.97
Larry, "2021-01-18 18:24:53", 127, 98, 72, 7.76
Curly, "2021-01-17 18:24:53", 126, 97, 82, 8.0
```

For each user, I would like to return the **DateTime of their latest measurement**, and their **temperature and bloodPressure** from their latest DateTime:

```
Larry, "2021-01-18 18:24:53", 127, 98
Mo, "2021-01-20 18:24:53", 130, 99
Curly, "2021-01-19 18:24:53", 121, 98
```

I tried this,

```
SELECT  
    c.userName,
    MAX(c.DateTime),
    c.bloodPressure, 
    c.temperature
FROM CheckupData c
GROUP BY 
    c.userName
```

but got an error that GROUP BY should include the other outputs of SELECT. Since bloodPressure and temperature are always changing, it seems like I shouldn't use them in GROUP BY, because I only want the lastest values. What am I doing wrong?
(If it matters, my real database is larger: 50,000 userNames measured at 50 or so DateTime values each, and 30 or so columns).

Comment: If CosmosDB doesn't have window functions, then you want greatest-n-per-group  - if user_name is  a PK, then you should be able to SELECT c.user_name, MAX(c.date_time) AS mdt FROM checkup_data c GROUP BY c.user_name and then join that back to checkup_data on the PK and mdt - taking the bp and temp... I did something like this today [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/289508/34007) - there's links within also.

Comment: I threw together [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=680627a26edc923554cc302f14e169fb) - if no window functions are available...

Comment: Thanks Verace. I think JOIN ON is different for Azure Cosmos. [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join) only has JOIN IN. I will try to adapt your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an environment to test with, but the below might work for you.

EDIT: I see now that this is the same approach as @Verace's comment, but still, it should work in Cosmos DB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery

```
SELECT c.userName
    , c.DateTime 
    , c.bloodPressure
    , c.temperature
FROM CheckupData c
    JOIN  (SELECT g.userName, MAX(g.DateTime) AS MaxDateTime FROM CheckupData g GROUP BY g.userName) m
WHERE m.userName = c.userName 
    AND m.MaxDateTime = c.DateTime
```

Comment: When I tried this query in the Cosmos portal it said "We have detected you may be using a subquery. Non-correlated subqueries are not currently supported.  Please see Cosmos [sub query documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery) for further information". When I ran the query, I got the error "Identifier CheckupData could not be resolved." [Here](https://christosmonogios.com/2017/12/17/The-Reason-Behind-The-Identifer-Could-Not-Be-Resolved-Error-In-Your-CosmosDB-Queries/) is some info on that that I will look at.

Answer (score 0):

**EVERY** Column in a `SELECT` has to be in the `GROUP BY` or use a [aggregator function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT  
    c.userName,
    MAX(c.DateTime),
    c.bloodPressure, 
    c.temperature
FROM CheckupData c
GROUP BY 
    c.userName,c.bloodPressure, c.temperature
```

OR

```
SELECT  
    c.userName,
    MAX(c.DateTime),
    AVG(c.bloodPressure), 
    AVG(c.temperature)
FROM CheckupData c
GROUP BY 
    c.userName
```

As we don't know nothing about your data and desired result. You have to choose what values you need.

For **big** tables you can use

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CheckupData 
>     ([userName] varchar(5), [DateTime] varchar(21), [bloodPressure] int, [temperature] int, [heartBeat] int, [hatSize] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO CheckupData 
>     ([userName], [DateTime], [bloodPressure], [temperature], [heartBeat], [hatSize])
> VALUES
>     ('Curly', '"2021-01-19 18:24:53"', 121, 98, 60, 7.25),
>     ('Larry', '"2021-01-14 18:24:53"', 125, 99, 80, 7.5),
>     ('Mo', '"2021-01-13 18:24:53"', 123, 100, 70, 7.75),
>     ('Curly', '"2021-01-18 18:24:53"', 120, 97, 50, 8),
>     ('Larry', '"2021-01-13 18:24:53"', 119, 99, 75, 7.15),
>     ('Larry', '"2021-01-15 18:24:53"', 115, 98, 85, 7.37),
>     ('Mo', '"2021-01-12 18:24:53"', 110, 102, 100, 8.01),
>     ('Mo', '"2021-01-20 18:24:53"', 130, 99, 110, 6.97),
>     ('Larry', '"2021-01-18 18:24:53"', 127, 98, 72, 7.76),
>     ('Curly', '"2021-01-17 18:24:53"', 126, 97, 82, 8.0)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> cd.[userName], cd.[DateTime], cd.[bloodPressure], cd.[temperature], cd.[heartBeat], cd.[hatSize]
> FROM CheckupData cd INNER JOIN 
> (SELECT MAX([DateTime]) lastdate,[userName] FROM CheckupData GROUP BY [userName]) cd1
> ON cd.[userName]  = cd1.[userName] AND cd.[DateTime] = cd1.lastdate
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> userName | DateTime              | bloodPressure | temperature | heartBeat | hatSize
> :------- | :-------------------- | ------------: | ----------: | --------: | ------:
> Mo       | "2021-01-20 18:24:53" |           130 |          99 |       110 |       6
> Larry    | "2021-01-18 18:24:53" |           127 |          98 |        72 |       7
> Curly    | "2021-01-19 18:24:53" |           121 |          98 |        60 |       7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3749a7109d8e6fad39dae74d9fed1e53)*

Comment: I added example data to my question, thanks for pointing out that was needed. Is there an aggregator function instead of AVG that will find the bloodPressure and temperature value that was measured at the MAX(c.DateTime) for each user?

Comment: @KAE i added a query for your question.

Comment: Thanks so much. Unfortunately it seems like Cosmos DB doesn't allow INNER JOIN, or the square bracket convention like cd.[userName]. It is really hard to figure out how to write a complicated Cosmos DB query that works since it's using its own flavor of SQL. I may just dump all the data out and do it by brute force.

Comment: There is a SQL query test tool for Azure Cosmos DB [here](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo) that seems useful for learning it, so I'll see if that helps.

Comment: you can use simokly join the inner is implicit and remove the brackets

Comment: Person has asked for Cosmos DB.  I think they have mistakenly put in "tsql" as a tag, which has confused things. This answer won't work for Cosmos DBs where a join is internal to the document, not to another table.

Comment: @blobbles according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/subquery this work perfectly in cosmodb, so did you get an error?

Comment: @nbk - you do know the SQL API for Cosmos is it's own implementation of SQL? The above is tsql, NOT the Cosmos SQL API version.  As KAE said, INNER JOIN is not part of the language. CREATE TABLE isn't a thing, they don't have tables, they have containers. It looks like you don't understand that it's and entirely different SQL implementation, JOINs in Cosmos are internal to the document, cos its a document DB. Your fiddle is for SQL Server, not Cosmos. Also you should be testing your code before you submit an answer, not me, I can see it's not going to work just by looking at it.

Comment: as they are similar and the query works in comosdb, it really doesn't matter if the fiddle is in sql server to understand that it works

Comment: @nbk OK, just for your information, I tried your SQL Create statement in Cosmos:
ERROR: One of the input values is invalid. I tried your INSERT statement: ERROR: One of the input values is invalid.  I tried your SELECT statement: ERROR: One of the input values is invalid. Its a completely different implementation of SQL. Clearly you don't understand this.

Comment: @nbk - there is no INSERT INTO statement. No CREATE TABLE statement in Cosmos.  You aren't understanding that it's not a relational DB model like SQL Server.  Maybe start in Microsofts getting started pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/getting-started  and check the first blue box for important info